# NullPointerException in android AsyncTask in method innerSetException():

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mediastore

In the app on which I a working I have a method called addVideo which gets called in the doInBackground method of an AsyncTask, which basically just adds a video to the media store and returns its uri:

```
 public Uri addVideo(File videoFile) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "My Video!");
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
    return getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

I am currently getting an error on the line:
`values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");`

Here is the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myProject.add_video_project.AddToMediaStore.addVideo(Submit.java:121)
at com.myProject.add_video_project.AddToMediaStore$StartUploadChain.doInBackground(Submit.java:195)
at com.myProject.add_video_project.AddToMediaStore$StartUploadChain.doInBackground(Submit.java:167)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on? Thanks!

Comment: Try this .. comment out all of the lines and see if it is something in the method, or something elsewhere in how the task is launched. If it works with all of them commented out, then add the lines back in one by one until it breaks.

Comment: Also, sometimes I see errors reported one line off, so it could be the line after, maybe getAbsolutePath() is returning a null

Comment: Try to detect if you can find that file on that location that you are trying to find. Write out path or check for null pointer. Advice above is good also.

Comment: Make sure videoFile file is not null too, my guess is that it is

Comment: The actual cause is Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myProject.add_video_project.AddToMediaStore.addVideo(Submit.java:121), so go to this line in your code and try to figure what is null there.